# Copy SFTP private key from one server to another

Tags: linux, connection, sftp, solaris

Earlier we were establishing SFTP connections to destination servers through a Solaris host. We are now migrating from Solaris to Linux as part of new initiative to save cost. We have about 112 destination hosts and since these jobs have been running for past 20 years, and it is becoming quite cahllenging for us to contact owners for these destinations.

To fasten the process, we are thinking of copying the Solaris' private key to Linux new server. We did a small POC with one destination server and it seemed to work.

1. Has anyone done this same in past?
2. Could this pose any problems such as new connection being blocked by destination?
3. Are there any chances that decommissioning of Solaris server will impacts the connections going through new Linux server?

Any experience with this would help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: You question is not very clear. I believe you used to connect to you servers from you solaris machines now you wan to do the same from your linux machines without making any changes in the destination servers. To do that  all you have to do is copy the solaris(the first host) private key to the linux (new hosts ). You can check the connection with `ssh -T user@hostname`. If you can not place the private key at default location, you may explicitly specify that in sftp command `sftp -oIdentityFile=/path/to/private/keyfile`

Comment: thanks @terminalninja .. I have already done that..just wanted to confirm that is there any possibility that destination server can verify the host is still alive or not  from where the key is generated ?
In my case I am planning to remove the Solaris in near future,and my keys are genrated from Solaris. so is there any chance that i can face connectivity failure once i will remove Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with this migration if you copy all the private keys to the linux.

Please be aware the permissions of the .ssh folder may vary depending on the linux distribution that you choose.

Also, it will be wise to keep the Solaris machine around, poweroff of course, as a "private key backup" until you see that everyting is OK with the linux server.